# Gmail security and accounts

Tags: gmail, google-passwords

My Gmail account has 2 step verification but a guy knows when I created my account. Will he be able to change the password?

Answer (score 1):

If the guy doesn't know 2 step verification security code then he would not be able to change the the password. But make sure he doesn't have the details you have filled at the account creation time, otherwise it will be easy for him to reset the password.

Security tip: Do not share any details related to your account to anyone. If you have doubt that someone knows any detail about your account, just change those details.

Comment: How do I change the account creation date

Comment: You can't change account creation date but you can change your password, security question's answer etc.